# How to use php variable inside another one

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find the category ID of a post and then use it in the short code below. To find the category id I'm using `<?php the_category_ID(); ?>`, but i'm not sure how to use the output from category id and replace it in include_categories=. i.e. i want to replace number 4 with the current category ID i got from `<?php the_category_ID(); ?>`.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[include_categories="4"]'); ?>
```

i tired doing the following, but it didn't work. Any ideas will be appreciated.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[include_categories="<?php the_category_ID(); ?>"]'); ?>
```

I know i can't use php inside another php code, but i'm not sure how to place the category id between the quotation.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't ever have `<?php` or `?>` inside existing php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with -

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[include_categories="'.the_category_ID().'"]'); ?>
```

Comment: [the_category_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category_ID) has been deprecated since 0.71...

Comment: Thanks sgt. it worked perfectly! i was just wondering why did use the single quotes '' inside the double quotes/

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things: (1) you can't have nested `<?php  ?>` tags, (2) [the_category_ID()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category_ID) has been deprecated since WordPress 0.71. You'll want to use [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) instead.

The correct solution would be:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[include_categories="' . get_the_category() . '"]'); ?>
```

The dots `.` "concatenate" the string with the `return`ed values of `get_the_category()`. You can read more about [string operators in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score -1):

Use this to add php verial in short code:

```
<?php $category=the_category_ID(); 
  echo do_shortcode("[include_categories=$category]"); ?>
```